# Downloads of .apk files in android browsers from my webapp unsuccessful ( ClientAbortException )

Tags: android, download, server, ioexception, apk-expansion-files

I need to host .apk files, in a website, to be downloaded from android devices browsers. I'm using a servlet on the server side.
To request the download,i use this url http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/root/AppsServlet.do?id=arg which i typed in the a tag of the download page

- I have set the content type as vnd.android.package-archive

  `response.setContentType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");`
- I have added the apk mime tag in the server's default-web.xml (glassfish) even in the webapp's deployement descriptor.

  apk
  application/vnd.android.package-archive

  - I connect my phone to the server(my laptop) through a wifi net.

Here is a piece of code from the servlet

```
void sendApk(HttpServletResponse response, String pckg){

    FilesManager fm = new FilesManager(FilesManager.APPS_KEY);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    File apkFile = fm.getApkFile(pckg);
    if(apkFile!= null){

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\""+apkFile.getName()+"\"");
        response.setHeader("Content-Description","File Transfert");
        response.setHeader("Content-Transfert_Encoding","binary");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(apkFile); 
            //byte [] apkBytes = new byte[fis.available()];
            response.setContentLength(fis.available());
            //response.setHeader("Content-Length",fis.available()+"");
            os = response.getOutputStream();

           //java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(apkFile.getAbsolutePath()));
           // int read = fis.read(apkBytes);

            //fis.close();

            System.out.println(response.getHeaderNames());
           // os.write(apkBytes, 0, apkBytes.length);
           // os.flush();
            Utils.copyFileStream(fis, os);//Here's the line 76
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AppsServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
          catch(IOException i){
            Logger.getLogger(AppsServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, i);
          }

        finally{
           if(fis !=  null){
                  try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AppsServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
           }

           if(os !=null){
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AppsServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
           }

        }

    }
```

Here's the method to transfert the bytes from Utils class

```
 public static void copyFileStream(FileInputStream is, OutputStream os){

    final int buffer_size = 20480;
    try{
      byte [] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];

      for(;;){

        int count = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer_size);
        if(count == -1) 
            break;

        os.write(buffer, 0, count);//Here's (Utils.java:50)

          }
              os.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

}
```

But after every test and every change in the code, still fails and always displays the following error in the server's log

SEVERE: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:430)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:385)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:160)
    at com.dimania.Utils.copyFileStream(Utils.java:50)
    at com.dimania.AppsServlet.sendApk(AppsServlet.java:76)
    at com.dimania.AppsServlet.processRequest(AppsServlet.java:44)
    at com.dimania.AppsServlet.doGet(AppsServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:108)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:426)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:498)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes0(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:382)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:364)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:894)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:159)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:661)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.doWrite(Response.java:685)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:425)
    ... 34 more

Helps will be highly appreciated

Comment: You should have started telling us how the used url looks like.

Comment: `Here's the method from Utils`. Which method? Please post the complete method .

Comment: `..t com.dimania.AppsServlet.sendApk(AppsServlet.java:72)`. Show complete sendApk function and tell which line is 72.